# Test for an active service worker from within the client

Tags: client, es6-promise, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, registration

From within my `client.js`, I register a service worker with:

```js
var someVariable;

if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js')
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Service worker registered.');
        if(localStorage.someVariable) {
            someVariable = JSON.parse(localStorage.someVariable);
        };
    });
};
```

Now, further down my `client.js` code, I would like to check whether `client.js` has an **active** service worker up and running.

Doing so from within `service-worker.js` would somewhat correspond to testing for `self.registration`, as `self.registration.active` does not seem to work.

However, what would be the equivalent test for an active service worker from within `client.js`?

`navigator.serviceWorker.ready` retuns a `Promise`, but I do not know if this is really what I need for use in/as a conditional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Your options

If you want to check whether the current page is under the control of *some* service worker at the current moment, you can examine [`navigator.serviceWorker.controller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/controller). It will be `null` if the current page is not controlled by a service worker, and set to a `ServiceWorker` instance if it is controlled by one.

If you want to check if the service worker associated with a given `ServiceWorkerRegistration` is active at a given point in time, you can do that with code like:

```
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
// Examine `registration.active` to see if, at the current point in time,
// there's an active service worker.
```

If you want to write code that will *wait* until there's any active service worker associated with the current page's service worker registration, then `await navigator.serviceWorker.ready` will do that for you.

#### active vs. controlling

Just a quick note on the difference between an active service worker, and a controlling service worker. A service worker can be active but not in control of any client pages—this is what would happen the first time a service worker is registered for a given scope if the service worker doesn't call [`clients.claim()`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#clientsclaim).

If you are calling `clients.claim()` in your service worker, then the distinction between active and controlling can mostly be ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the very useful elaboration concerning `clients.claim()`, which was not mentioned in the 2017 book I read about PWAs. This is precisely what the doctor ordered! By the way, the link on your profile is no longer working.